# How to format a timedelta like "1 hour ago" in python so that it is translatable

Tags: python, datetime, internationalization

I want to format a python timedelta object as "x minutes/hours/weeks/month/years ago".

I know there are some similar questions, like:

- [How to display "x days ago" type time using Humanize in Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494921/how-to-display-x-days-ago-type-time-using-humanize-in-django-template?rq=1)
- [From: "1 hour ago", To: timedelta + accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839642/from-1-hour-ago-to-timedelta-accuracy)
- [User-friendly time format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551382/user-friendly-time-format-in-python/1551394#1551394)

However, I did not find an answer for my case, because

- I do not use django
- I need to format a `timedelta` to a string, not the other way around
- The solution should work in as many languages as possible, not just English

Here is my current code (excerpt, sorry):

```
delta = babel.dates.format_timedelta(now - dt, format=format,          
                                     locale=locale)                       
if now > dt:                                                           
    return _(u"%(timedelta)s ago") % {'timedelta': delta}              
else:                                                                  
    return _(u"in %(timedelta)s") % {'timedelta': delta}
```

For the `babel` function, see http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/dates/#time-delta-formatting

Now this works fine in English. In German, however, it fails:
The above code would translate `"2 years ago"` to `"vor 2 Jahre"` instead of `"vor 2 Jahren"`.

I would also be happy with a solution that does not use the `"... ago"` phrasing. As long as it is similar and translatable I can accept it.

Comment: Requests for libraries etc are off-topic here, but you could look into [Arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation I found [here](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/stable/api/dates.html), you should add the `add_direction=True` parameter to your `format_timedelta` call.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick example that should put you on the right track:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> delta = datetime.timedelta(days=2)
>>> delta.days
2
>>> print delta
2 days, 0:00:00
```

You should create your formatting as it makes sense, perhaps someone else can put you on to an answer out of the box here.

```
>>> '{0} ago'.format(delta)
'2 days, 0:00:00 ago'
```

### A function for the timedelta object

```
def total_hours(a_timedelta):
    return a_timedelta.total_seconds()/60.0/60.0
```

Usage:

```
>>> total_hours(delta)
48.0
>>> '{0} hours ago'.format(total_hours(delta))
'48.0 hours ago'
>>> then = datetime.datetime.now() 
>>> diff = datetime.datetime.now() - then
>>> diff
datetime.timedelta(0, 12, 967773)
>>> '{0} hours ago'.format(total_hours(diff))
'0.00360215916667 hours ago'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the arrow package, especially the humanize function :

```
import arrow
a = arrow.now()
print a.humanize()
```

Output : "just now"

For your needs, suppose you have a date like:

```
myDate = "2019-02-10 08:00:00"
a = arrow.get(myDate, "YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm:ss")
print a.humanize()
```

Output : "an hour ago"

You can find the doc here : https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/